# wordpress favicon not working properly on all browsers

Tags: favicon, google-chrome

Curious fact: the favicon works only on admin dashboard on chrome/opera.

I've tried to clean the cache, but still not work. The line of code to the favicon its being included, buts it just doesnt work.

[image: favicon including codehtml]

I'm including the favicon through admin panel, to be dynamic. I just dont want to include it direct on the code.

---

- Firefox (Works)
- Edge (Works)
- Tor (Works)
- Chrome (Works only on admin dashboard)
- Opera (Works only on admin dashboard)

Comment: Sorry, but it is just impossible to guess what is going wrong on **your** server based on this info. If this happens with wordpress "vanila" themes, you should report it as a bug. If it happens with some other theme, you should contact the theme author.

Comment: Go to customize -> site identity and add favicon their

Comment: Yes, I have exactly same issue, only Chrome WP frontend not working. If you insert Icon with default Appearance -> Customize, somehow it works. But not with custom code, custom code works on backend it means codes are correct tho.

Answer (score 0):

try adding type="image/png" in the link definition.

Additionally Chrome is a little bit harder to clean the favicon cache (needs also a restart)

[This thread can help you perhaps, there are several hints there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780402/html-favicon-wont-show-on-google-chrome?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The other thing is, I remember have read somewhere, that it is best practice to have the favicons in the root folder, not the wp-content/uploads/ folder

Comment: the thing is: im uploading the favicon dynamically through the dashboard, then im not in control of where the uploads go. Anyway, thanks for helping.

Comment: i get that... altough: it's not a very common issue that the favicon changes, in fact all the opposite. It shouldn't change often. I normally use the https://realfavicongenerator.net/ to generate icons and html code for the header, which I include manually in the header.php of the theme itself... in fact it makes a nearly too broad support, but I never had problems. As suggested above my Mark Kaplun, one of your problems is that depending on which theme you use, you have no control over the code produced, so it's harder to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and it took me forever to figure it out! I don't know WHY but Chrome was the only browser that wouldn't see the favicon that was uploaded through Wordpress (and it WOULD show the favicon when on the admin page).

What finally worked for me was uploading a file named favicon.ico to my root public directory (using FTP). It's just a jpg, re-named favicon.ico. After I did that, Chrome would see it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! although the goal of having opened this issue was the problem by including the icon dynamically. Anyway, thanks for helping. I've already gave up and currently i'm including the favicon directly on the code, same as you! :D

Comment: Yes, I have exactly same issue, only Chrome WP frontend not working. If you insert Icon with default Appearance -> Customize, somehow it works. But not with custom code, custom code works on backend it means codes are correct tho.